# How do I typehint a potentially undefined variable in php?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I inject a variable (`$potentiallyUndefinedVariable`) in a php template. Yet since it happens at multiple places it may be undefined / unset and that is fine for me. I don't want to touch all the dozen other places only to inject a `false` value but I am fine with using the null coalescing operator within the template:

```
if ($potentiallyUndefinedVariable ?? false) { ... } // WON'T THROW: E_NOTICE: Undefined variable
```

Yet I very much do want do document to other developers that the variable may be undefined. Is there anything I can add in the phpdoc?

Right now I only have:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var boolean $potentiallyUndefinedVariable
 */
```

but that is lying. Best case scenario is that your IDE would warn when you forget to check that this variable was set.

I want to inform anybody who comes after me to use the null coalescing operator when using that variable.

Comment: Undefined would equate to null so you can make it a nullable value `@var null|boolean $potentiallyUndefinedVariable`

Comment: @JohnConde True, but it won't warn for the `E_NOTICE ` edge case.

Comment: I was hoping to do `@var undefined|boolean`, but that causes the ide to think that undefined is a class method. So I guess `@var null|boolean` is best, but I did find that `@var ?boolean` works as well.